# send_file Rails 2 Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jrubyonrails

In my Rails (2.3.10). I found some weird issue. My application needs to download a XML file when a user hit the downloaded URL.

For example :

http://www.example.com/test/all.xml

The problem here is, If I hit the url with alias name (http://www.example.com/test/all.xml). the XML not get downloaded.

If I hit production direct URL like http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/test/all.xml . The XML started downloading without any problem.

Can any one help on this. ? Please

Here is my code  in Test controller :

```
def index     
  file_path="/tmp/all.xml"    
  send_file file_path, :type => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'    
end
```

I have placed the  "all.xml" file into my production server /tmp/all.xml.

I am using  Jruby(1.6.5) and a WAR file is deploying to Tomcat....

Comment: What does "the XML not get downloaded." mean? Any error messages? What does your log file say? Also try adding `:disposition => 'attachment'` to the `send_file` line.

Comment: Anand Thanks for your reply.... let me try and let you know

Comment: Anand, the prob still there .eventhough i added :disposition => 'attachment'.  Does it related to Buffer size. My Xml size is 165MB

Answer (score 0):

so production is running on port 80, but the application server is running on port 3000. What server is doing the redirect. I'd look to the configuration of that server.